# How to display an array from JSON as a select option using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am learning this trade and wanted to know how to display JSON data correctly.

I have the following JSON data:

```
{ "dataFilters":{
         "eventType":[
            "Mobile Internet"
         ],
         "destination":[
            "United Kingdom"
         ],
         "usageType":[
            "All Usage",
            "Exceeded my Allowance",
            "Not included in my Allowance"
         ]
      },
      "voiceFilters":{
         "eventType":[
            "Special Voice Calls",
            "Voice minutes",
            "Three-to-Three minutes"
         ],
         "destination":[
            "Premium Rate Number",
            "Mobile",
            "3 Mobile",
            "Voicemail",
            "Iver"
         ],
         "usageType":[
            "All Usage",
            "Exceeded my Allowance",
            "Not included in my Allowance"
         ]
      },
      "msgFilters":{
         "eventType":[
            "Usage Message Event"
         ],
         "destination":[
            "India",
            "Mobile"
         ],
         "usageType":[
            "All Usage",
            "Exceeded my Allowance",
            "Not included in my Allowance"
         ]
      }
   }
```

if someone could help and maybe provide a solution or example id be very grateful.

thank you

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What code have you got so far? What data do you need in the select list - there seems to be a number of candidates here.

Comment: Hello RGraham, tahkns for responding. I need the 'dataFilters', 'voiceFilters' and 'msgFilters' displayed as <select> drop-downs. eventType, destination and usageType are the labels and the data within those arrays are what i need as <option> in the select form element. thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
var optns = $.map( json.dataFilters.usageType, function( value, key ) {
  return "<option value=" + key + ">" + value+ "</option>";
});

$("#selectId").append(optns);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cZf2t/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, i just have one issue, once i have put the code into my function, it just displays an empty select box, im sure im doing something very simple wrong, could you point it out! thanks. this is my code:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {




 $.getJSON('getCustomerUsage.js',function(data){



//PAGE HEADER
$("#EDBpageHeader").append('<h1>'+data.propertyList['ux.billsummary.page.title']+'</h1>');


var optns = $.map( json.dataFilters.usageType, function( type, key ) {
  return "<option value=" + key + ">" + type + "</option>";
});

$("#selectId").append(optns);
);

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $.getJSON('getCustomerUsage.js',function(data){



//PAGE HEADER
$("#EDBpageHeader").append('<h1>'+data.propertyList['ux.billsummary.page.title']+'</h1>');


var optns = $.map( json.dataFilters.usageType, function( type, key ) {
  return "<option value=" + key + ">" + type + "</option>";
});

$("#selectId").append(optns);

};

Comment: Could anyone possible point me in the right way?

Comment: try replacing json.dataFilters.usageType with data.dataFilters.usageType

Comment: Thank you Wilmer, I tried that but i incorporate the code into my page it breaks, the script tag is below, any help is appreciated, i understand it must be frustating to people in the know but im kinda knew on all this.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {




 $.getJSON('getCustomerUsage.js',function(data){


  var optns = $.map( data.dataFilters.usageType, function( type, key ) {
  return "<option value=" + key + ">" + type + "</option>";
});

$("#selectId").append(optns);



});


});
 

</script>

Comment: Could anyone help me on this, i know im doing something if not a lot wrong,